# Linking custom iOS buttons to footer nav buttons

Tags: ios, navigation

Im going to say this straight up - I'm an xcode noob. I am designing an app which has custom buttons on the home screen as well as a footer nav with buttons. When I select the custom button it goes to the right view but the footer nav button is not highlighted.

I just need to find a way to tell the footer nav i am on that section (got their by clicking on the home button). Apparently i have been told there is no way to do this so i might as well scrap my home view custom buttons. I'm hoping to find someone here with a different view. I would provide a screenshot so it makes my explanation clearer  but i have not got a high enough rating.

Originally i just wanted to hide the nav bar for the home screen but i was also told that it was not possible. Its there the whole time or not at all. Looking for a second opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to hide navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```

Also, just wanted to confirm, when you say footer navigation buttons, do you mean a tabbed view? some thing like [this screenshot?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQT9B.png)

If you could provide some screenshots would be great.